# Is there a way to pass hash value from webpack to vueJS application

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I am new to webpack and I am trying to add one hash value to the js file inside vueJS application whenever new build happened to avoid caching. Using webpack `ExtendedApiPlugin` tried to pass the hash value to the `template.ejs` file, but it throws error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: __webpack_hash__ is not defined`. Referred multiple forums and posts and everywhere it is mentioned similar like this, but it is not working for me as expected. I have defined the plugin in `webpack.config.js` file like below,

**webpack.config.js**

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'),
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'template.ejs'),
            inject: true
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin()
    ]
```

**webpack.config.dev.js**

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new WriteFilePlugin()
    ]
```

This is **template.ejs** file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/inject.js"></script>
        <% } %>
        <div id="my-app">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script> var val = __webpack_hash__; console.log("111111"); console.log(val) </script>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make this work or any other option to pass the hash value from webpack config to html file. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Solution:**

Found the solution after multiple attempts. We can use the following format to fetch the `__webpack_hash__` value,

`let webpackHash = <%= __webpack_hash__ %>;`

Comment: To me this last code snippet looks like valid HTML, not EJS. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: @Marcel Sorry, missed to add few things. Updated code is my template.ejs

Comment: Is this just for usage with hot module replacement at development time? Then you could also force the browser to just never cache a file. It's in the Chrome Dev Tools for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/79485

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after multiple attempts. We can use the following format to fetch the `__webpack_hash__` value,

`let webpackHash = <%= __webpack_hash__ %>;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack by default replaces some variables in the build output.

You could do:

```
//vue.config.js

//Setting the environment variables
const child_process = require('child_process');
function git(command) {
    return child_process
        .execSync(`git ${command}`, { encoding: 'utf8' })
        .trim();
}
process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version;
process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_VERSION = git('describe --always');
process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_AUTHOR_DATE = git('log -1 --format=%aI');
```

Then in the relevant file something like (this is just an example, no need to actually use this on an icon...):

```
<link
    rel="apple-touch-icon"
    href="<%= BASE_URL %>/img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png?v=<%= process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_VERSION %>"
/>
```

This will do the trick for circumventing any caching for each new build. And technically the git version is actually already a hash.

---

I have this working for an about page in my web app at https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa, if you want to look it up there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, So we cannot use ExtendedAPIPlugin ? That option will not work at all?

Comment: @DeepakKumar To be honest, I don't know. This is just my solution, it works, but there surely must be others, maybe even using this Plugin.